# Clone all last columns dropdown javascript on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to clone the nth all columns of the html table where as my code converts only the last lows last column Dropdown on click  i need all the dropdown of last column to be duplicated

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shaikasifpasha3/kQpfE/247/)

Example Present Status :

```
Day1 Dropdown 1

1      dd

2      dd

3      dd       dd

 on click
```

Expected out Put

```
Day1 Dropdown 1     Dropdown 2

1      dd              dd

2      dd              dd

3      dd              dd
```

HTML:

```
<table id='tableID'>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>
           Dropdown1
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
            <select id="BodyHolder_DD_Sub1" style="height:27px;width:150px;">
                <option value="Select Subject">Select Subject</option>
                <option value="Holiday">Holiday</option>
                <option value="Lunch">Lunch</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="ECO-17">ECO-17</option>
                <option value="ECO-19">ECO-19</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>
            <select id="BodyHolder_DD_Sub1" style="height:27px;width:150px;">
                <option value="Select Subject">Select Subject</option>
                <option value="Holiday">Holiday</option>
                <option value="Lunch">Lunch</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="ECO-17">ECO-17</option>
                <option value="ECO-19">ECO-19</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>
            <select id="BodyHolder_DD_Sub1" style="height:27px;width:150px;">
                <option value="Select Subject">Select Subject</option>
                <option value="Holiday">Holiday</option>
                <option value="Lunch">Lunch</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="ECO-17">ECO-17</option>
                <option value="ECO-19">ECO-19</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" id="clone" value="Add New Row"></button>
```

JS:

```
$("#clone").on("click",function(){

var $tableBody = $('#tableID').find("tbody"),
        $trLast = $tableBody.find("td:last"),
        $trNew = $trLast.clone();

    $trLast.after($trNew);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to clone the th and add a value. This would work for now -> http://jsfiddle.net/kQpfE/248/

```
   $("#clone").on("click", function () {   
          var newHeader = $('#tableID thead tr').append('<th></th>');
          $('#tableID').find('th:last()').append('Dropdown' + ($('#tableID thead tr th').length - 1));
          $.each($('#tableID tbody').find('tr'), function (i, v) {
              $(v).append($(v).find('td:last()').clone());
        });  
   });
```

Edit: Forgot to mention your use of the same ID Multiple times as well as your TH being in the Tbody, perhaps clean up your HTML first.

Edit2: After a screensharing session adapted the code to add the th and increment.

Comment: Thanks for the ans was expecting exactly the same

Comment: sure as u say but i need a little help of ur if u dont mind can you join me hear  http://jsfiddle.net/kQpfE/248/#&togetherjs=gR0cBtTyuF

Comment: if u can team viewer me i can share my id and pass

Comment: I'm not familiar with c# or ASP so not sure if I can help much further man

Comment: Ok cool no issue let me check on google if i can find any thing

Comment: bro the issue was in asp on button cick the page gets pre load to load the server data so as or code creates a dynimic Columns they ware getting erased the solution was simple i added  `return false;`  on click event's ending tag

Comment: hi need some help regarding some condition issue this u might solve

Answer (score 1):

Change your html for this, cuz you were not using thead:

```
<table id='tableID'>
    <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>day</th>
        <th>
           Dropdown1
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
            <select id="BodyHolder_DD_Sub1" style="height:27px;width:150px;">
                <option value="Select Subject">Select Subject</option>
                <option value="Holiday">Holiday</option>
                <option value="Lunch">Lunch</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="ECO-17">ECO-17</option>
                <option value="ECO-19">ECO-19</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>
            <select id="BodyHolder_DD_Sub1" style="height:27px;width:150px;">
                <option value="Select Subject">Select Subject</option>
                <option value="Holiday">Holiday</option>
                <option value="Lunch">Lunch</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="ECO-17">ECO-17</option>
                <option value="ECO-19">ECO-19</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>
            <select id="BodyHolder_DD_Sub1" style="height:27px;width:150px;">
                <option value="Select Subject">Select Subject</option>
                <option value="Holiday">Holiday</option>
                <option value="Lunch">Lunch</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="ECO-17">ECO-17</option>
                <option value="ECO-19">ECO-19</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" id="clone" value="Add New Row"></button>
```

And your script for this:

```
$("#clone").on("click",function(){

var $tableBody = $('#tableID').find("tbody"),
        $tableHead = $('#tableID').find("thead"),
        $trLast = $tableBody.find("td:last");

    $tableHead.find("tr").each(function(){ $(this).append($("<th>Dropdown "+ $tableHead.find("th").size() - 1  +"</th>")); });
    $tableBody.find("tr").each(function(){ $(this).append($trLast.clone()); });
});
```

Comment: Need ur help can i have your some of the time

Comment: Sorry, I had to leave.

Comment: Cool no issue Thnks for ur support